# Why is {2, {2}} not a subset of {{2}, {2, {2}}}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why is A not a subset of B?

A = {2, {2}}

B = {{2}, {2, {2}}}

Comment: Because $2\in \{2,\{2\}\}$ but $2\notin \{\{2\},\{2,\{2\}\}\}$.

Comment: A is not a *subset* of B. It is an *element* of B.

Comment: $\{\{2,\{2\}\}\}$ (notice the extra braces) would be a subset of $B$.

Comment: $B$ has two elements: $A$ and $2$.  $B$ has four subsets: the trivial $\emptyset$ and $B$ and the sets with one element each $\{A\}$ and $\{\{2\}\}$, none of which are $A$.

Comment: $A$ has two elements: $\{2\}$ and $2$.  $A$ has four subsets: the trivial $\emptyset$ and $A$ and the sets with one element each  $\{\{2\}\}$ and $\{2\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“A is a subset of B” means $\forall x \in A: x \in B$.

In this particular examples, $A$ is disqualified as a subset of $B$ because we have $2 \in A$ but $2 \not\in B$.

The fact that $B$ contains sets that *contain* $2$ is not relevant: Set membership is a “shallow” operator and doesn't look inside nested sets.  The integer $2$ is not the same thing as the set $\{2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$A\subseteq B\iff (\forall x)(x \in A \implies A \in B)$.

Yet:

$2\in A \land 2 \notin B$